# Creating graph on ggplot2 with facte_wrap using multiple seperate variables

Tags: variables, ggplot2, facet-wrap

For my thesis I am using R-studio. I want to make a graph on ggplot2 with x= age(H2_lft) and y = IMT value (Mean_IMT_alg). I want to plot a graph with multiple variables(cardiovascular risk factors) to see the relationship between a certain variable/cardiovascular risk factor (e.g. smoking(H2_roken)/gender(H1_geslacht)/ethnicity(H1_EtnTotaal) and the IMT value on a certain age.
First, I plotted multiple lines (each line represented a variable) in a graph. But I think this is a little too messy. I actually want to have multiple 'pannels/graphs' with x= age and y = IMT value. And in every graph I want to have a different variable.

I hope my explanation is clear enough and someone can help me :)

My first code (multiple lines in same plot) is:

```
t <- ggplot(data = Dataset, aes(x = H2_lft, y = MeanIMT_alg)) + 
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, aes(group = H1_EtnTotaal, colour = H1_EtnTotaal)) + 
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, aes(group = H2_Roken, colour = H2_Roken)) + 
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, aes(group = H1_geslacht, colour = H1_geslacht)) + 
  stat_smooth(method = lm, se=FALSE) + 
  theme_classic() 
t + labs(x = "Age (years)", y = "Mean IMT (mm)", title ="IMT", caption = "Figure 2: mean IMT", color = "cardiovascular risk factors", fil = "cardiovascular risk factors")
```

To accomplish multiple panels i used 'facet_wrap'. The problem however is that when using 'groups' in facet_Wrap, R makes groups that proceed on each other. But i want the groups to be unrelated of eachother. For example: I want one graph with a line for Marroccan ethnicity, one line with current smoking and one line with Male participants. I do not want a graph with: morroccan women that currently smoke or: Dutch men that never smoked. So, I want the graph with all the lines but split into several graphs.

The code that I used to accomplish this is:

```
t <- ggplot(data = Dataset, aes(x = H2_lft, y = MeanIMT_alg)) + 
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, aes(group = H1_EtnTotaal, colour = H1_EtnTotaal)) + 
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, aes(group = H2_Roken, colour = H2_Roken)) + 
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, aes(group = H1_geslacht, colour = H1_geslacht)) + 
  stat_smooth(method = lm, se=FALSE)+ 
  facet_wrap(~H1_EtnTotaal + ~H2_Roken + ~H1_geslacht, scales = "free_y") + 
  theme_classic() 
t + labs(x = "Age (years)", y = "Mean IMT (mm)", title ="IMT", caption = "Figure 2: mean IMT", color = "cardiovascular risk factors", fil = "cardiovascular risk factors")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be generally easier to reshape the data to a long format for plotting with ggplot2. If you want seperate legends for each of the categories, you can use the {ggnewscale} package to do so. Is this (approximately) what you're looking for?

```r
library(ggnewscale)
library(ggplot2)

# Dummy data
Dataset <- data.frame(
  H2_lft = runif(100, 18, 90),
  MeanIMT_alg = rnorm(100),
  H1_EtnTotaal = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 100, replace = TRUE),
  H2_Roken = sample(LETTERS[6:8], 100, replace = TRUE),
  H1_geslacht = sample(c("M", "F"), 100, replace = TRUE)
)

# Reshape data to long format
new <- tidyr::pivot_longer(Dataset, c(H1_EtnTotaal, H2_Roken, H1_geslacht))

ggplot(new, aes(H2_lft, MeanIMT_alg, group = value)) +
  geom_smooth(
    data = ~ subset(.x, name == "H1_EtnTotaal"),
    aes(colour = value), 
    se = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_colour_discrete(name = "EtnTotaal") +
  new_scale_colour() +
  geom_smooth(
    data = ~ subset(.x, name == "H1_geslacht"),
    aes(colour = value),
    se = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_colour_discrete(name = "geslacht") +
  new_scale_colour() +
  geom_smooth(
    data = ~ subset(.x, name == "H2_Roken"),
    aes(colour = value),
    se = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_colour_discrete(name = "Roken") +
  geom_smooth(
    method = lm, se = FALSE,
    aes(group = NULL)
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~ name)
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi, Thanks again for the help on getting multiple graphs. I am unfortunately still struggling with some specific things when using this code. When plotting the code, I get multiple graphs, which is what i wanted. However, in every graph, I get a blue diagonal line (implicating a linear association, I think the line of the association between age (H2_lft) and IMT (MeanIMT_alg) itself. I wish to not see this line in any graph. Also, I wish to also display some variables that are linear in stead of categorial. But when I try to do this, I only see the blue line. Do you know how to solve this?